# How to turn off light on Logitech G502 mouse?

Tags: mouse, logitech

The light on my Logitech G502 mouse is really stupid and annoying.
I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to turn it off than sticking wire tape on the shining area?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes should be possible. [libratbag](https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag/tree/master/data/devices) claims it supports:

> libratbag data files
>
> This directory contains the data files for each supported device. libratbag reads these files to identify the backend driver for any given device. If a device is not listed, libratbag will not support it.
>
> See the device.example file for instructions on the various options.

```
logitech-g502-hero-wireless.device
logitech-g502-hero.device
logitech-g502-proteus-core.device  
logitech-g502-proteus-spectrum.device
```

> Piper
>
> Piper is a GTK+ application to configure gaming mice. Piper is merely a graphical frontend to the ratbagd DBus daemon, see the libratbag README for instructions on how to run ratbagd.

[Installation](https://github.com/libratbag/piper):

```
 sudo apt install piper
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use ratbag library directly using the ratbagctl tool. For your mouse:

```
➜  ~ ratbagctl "Logitech G502 HERO Gaming Mouse" info                   
singing-gundi - Logitech G502 HERO Gaming Mouse
             Model: usb:046d:c08b:0
 Number of Buttons: 11
    Number of Leds: 2
Number of Profiles: 5
Profile 0:
  Name: n/a
  Report Rate: 1000Hz
  Resolutions:
    0: 1200dpi
    1: 1200dpi (active) (default)
    2: 3200dpi
    3: 6400dpi
    4: 0dpi
  Button: 0 is mapped to 'button 1'
  Button: 1 is mapped to 'button 2'
  Button: 2 is mapped to 'button 3'
  Button: 3 is mapped to 'button 4'
  Button: 4 is mapped to 'button 5'
  Button: 5 is mapped to 'resolution-alternate'
  Button: 6 is mapped to 'resolution-down'
  Button: 7 is mapped to 'resolution-up'
  Button: 8 is mapped to 'profile-cycle-up'
  Button: 9 is mapped to 'wheel-right'
  Button: 10 is mapped to 'wheel-left'
  LED: 0, depth: rgb, mode: off
  LED: 1, depth: rgb, mode: off
Profile 1: (disabled) (active)
Profile 2: (disabled)
Profile 3: (disabled)
Profile 4: (disabled)
```

Then to set something, you could use the following examples:

```
ratbagctl "Logitech G502 HERO Gaming Mouse" profile 0 led 1 set mode off
ratbagctl "Logitech G502 HERO Gaming Mouse" profile 0 dpi set 1200
```

If you do not know the name of the device, use `ratbagctl list`.